# Using custom CSS with jQuery validation?

Tags: jquery, css, validation, jquery-validate

How can I use a custom CSS class for the error messages?
I'd rather not style the standard label.error.  I want to use a CSS class I already have.

Comment: This question is really broad. http://www.whathaveyoutried.com

Comment: What's the difference? If you want to style ALL the error messages the same way, there's no reason not to use `label.error`.

Comment: It would be helpful to explicitly link to the validation library you are using.  I'm pretty sure it's the bassistance.de jQuery Validate, but other people might be confused!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an option for [jQuery Validate](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions) called `errorClass`:

> Use this class to create error labels, to look for existing error
>   labels and to add it to invalid elements.

All you need to do is specify it in your original `$.validate` call:

```
$('#myForm').validate({
   errorClass:'myClass'
   //your options
});
```

Answer (score -2):

You could do something like that:

html:

```
<form action="">
    <ul>
        <li><input type="text" id="name" value="Your name" /></li>
        <li><input type="submit" id="submit" /></li>
        <li class="error">
            <span>Ops!</span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

css:

> form .error {display:none;}

jquery:

```
$('form').submit(function(){
    if($('#name').val()==''||$('#name').val()=='Your name'){
        $('form .error').css({display: 'block'});
    }
})
```

Comment: -1 for not properly using the plugin... or using it at all.  It already has its own `submitHandler` event built-in, so no need to bind another function to form's `submit` event.  Additionally, since he's using the validation plugin, why would he write a custom validation function that does its own validation external to the plugin?  The answer makes no sense.

Comment: i am not veeery familiar with all the functions of the plugin, i just showed a way to fix the problem and this way works. its not the best way to solve the problem but it can fix the problem, its not efficiently but its effectively. you could -1 the answer if it didnt work at all right? thanks

Comment: Why would you post an answer about something you're not familiar?  I gave it a -1 because the answer is a really clumsy and impractical solution.  Why would the OP use the validation plugin if he wanted to re-write validation code from scratch?  And your answer may not actually work properly with the plugin.