# Input validation using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation, input

I am coding a MVC 5 internet application and I have a view where I would like to implement custom validation.

I have the following HTML element:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="txtCvc">Cvc</label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <input class="form-control text-box single-line" id="txtCvc" name="Cvc" type="text" value="" />
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I mark this HTML element as not valid in jQuery?

The effect of what I am looking for is this:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="txtCvc">Cvc</label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <input class="input-validation-error form-control text-box single-line" id="txtCvc" name="Cvc" type="text" value="" />
        <span class="field-validation-error" data-valmsg-for="test" data-valmsg-replace="true">Test error.</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

How is the best way to accomplish this? Do I need to manually add `"input-validation-error"` to the `id="txtCvc"` and then manually add the `span class="field-validation-error"`?

Is there an easier/better way to do this? I am not a regular user of jQuery.

There is no model for the HTML elements that I wish to use this validation for and a model CANNOT be used. The code is exactly as the first code in the post.

All I want to do is display a validation message for the HTML element, and have the red container outline around the input element. I wish to get the same result as if I have a Model with Data Annotations, yet with no model, and in jQuery/Javascript. Is there a jQuery library that can help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the razor view behind your HTML, what is the model?

Comment: What kind of custom validation do you need on the input?

Comment: Can you have a look at my edit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

document [.validate()](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate#toptions) use

```css
.field-validation-error {
    color: #b94a48;
    border: 1px solid #b94a48;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.13.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<form class="cmxform" id="commentForm" method="get" action="">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Please provide your name, email address (won't be published) and a comment</legend>
    <p>
      <label for="cname">Name (required, at least 2 characters)</label>
      <input id="cname" name="name" minlength="2" type="text" required>
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="cemail">E-Mail (required)</label>
      <input id="cemail" type="email" name="email" required>
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="curl">URL (optional)</label>
      <input id="curl" type="url" name="url">
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="ccomment">Your comment (required)</label>
      <textarea id="ccomment" name="comment" required></textarea>
    </p>
    <p>
      <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
    </p>
  </fieldset>
</form>
<script>
$("#commentForm").validate({
  
errorClass:'field-validation-error'
});
</script>
```

```
   $('#myForm').validate({ 
       errorClass:'myClass'   //your options 
    });
```

[jquery-validation/custom css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14447295/using-custom-css-with-jquery-validation)

Answer (score 0):

You can set the Required Attribute in the Model Property and then use this model here. Example

**Model** 
 
public class LoginModel{ 
[Required] 
public string TxtCvc{get;set;} 
}

**In your View**  
@model LoginModel 
@Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.TxtCvc)

Comment: There is no model for the HTML elements.

Comment: If you have a model and then you set property with required. When use submit this form automatically the class gets appended to the control. then we can just use css for your requirement. **input.input-validation-error, textarea.input-validation-error, select.input-validation-error, .input-validation-error {
    border: 1px solid #e80c4d !important;
}**

Comment: As I have said, there is no model, and a model cannot be used in this situation.

Comment: In Controller check if the text box has value and then if not add error using ModelState.AddError and then in View page add @Html.ValidationSummary. and then in client side on button click check if texbox has value if not add the border to the  textbox